# Authenticating multiple roles in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, laravel-5.3

i'm building an API which has `Driver`,`Agent` and `Admin` models
agent will be having a `mobile app` where as the admin will be given access to `Web app`.

i want authenticate Agents and Admin as well, i searched for resource hoe to do it but din't get any solution

so for i have installed `passport` and in `User` table added a user and tested using `POST MAN` it's working fine, i'm able to get access token

but i want to do the same authentication for the above models as well, i really don't know how to do it

i'm so confused now, looking forward for much needed help

Thank You

Comment: If I remember right, you can't have multiple Auth-models. Instead you could use Entrust (https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) and its Roles & Permissions functionality to archive your goal. An other benefit of Entrust ist, that you can manage permissions more precisely.

Comment: Needless to mention, `entrust` is a nice package. But if you want to do it yourself, you can create a `roles` table and a `permissions` table. Then you can map which user has which role and permission. Once it's done, you can check from your controller whether the user has required permission, then return some data, else return permission denied msg or something similar

Comment: @ThatMSG  @Arun Code  thank you so much for you time i really appreciate it,  i'm building an API for `mobile and web app`, the `agents` will be having `mobile app` where he can login to `CRUD` the `drivers` where as the `admin` will be give with web app where he can `CRUD` the `agents` since this is an `API` there is no session to store the `agents` and `admin` so i should provide `access token` for both `agents` and `admin` right? this is where i am stuck, should i make the `Agent` and 'Admin' model authenticatable to achive this? or is there any other way? thank you